# linux kernel module char device

Tags: linux, module, kernel, char, device

i'm writing a char device in linux - xubuntu , 
and i'm wondering if i have to implement ioctl OR
maybe i can use the regular read write funcs??

thanks all,
Amit

Comment: Well, what's the module for? Do you really need any `ioctl` s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary interface for a character device is the file functions, with ioctl serving extra, optional functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to kernel module programming, you might want to check out the [Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.faqs.org/docs/kernel/).

Answer (score 0):

The standard read/write functions are part of standard fops(file operations) structure in a character device driver model.If someone needs an additional functionality (which is user defined) and which is application dependent so you can go with ioctl() call.